# SAS proc sql - how to read in log of variable but retain the variable's label

Tags: sql, sas, label

I am reading in variables from a few different datasets using proc sql, which I am trying to improve on.

What I'd like to do is read in a variable from a dataset using proc sql, but take the log of the variable as it's read in, but keep the variable name.

```
PROC SQL;
  CREATE TABLE all AS
  SELECT DISTINCT a.*,
                  b.var1, LOG(b.var2) AS log_var2                    
  FROM pop AS a
  INNER JOIN trt AS b
    ON a.study=b.study AND a.subj=b.subj
  ;
QUIT;
```

The above creates a table with the variable log_var2, but it does not have the variable name from var2. Is there a way to keep this? The idea is that the label is used later on when transposing and the label is used as values within a table, but var2 itself may change so I need a robust method of labelling log_var2 with the label name from var2.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Just to clarify: I'm pretty sure you want the `variable label` from var2.  The variable label is what it looks like by default when you open the dataset, but can be different from the `variable name`, which is what you use to refer to it in a program.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know, there is not a way of persisting the variable label automatically in `proc sql`.  Unfortunately, you don't have access to the `vlabel` etc. functions, and even if you did the timing would be wrong to use them.

In addition to defining the label manually as yukclam9 shows, you *can* obtain that value using variable information functions, or perhaps more easily in a data step beforehand.  This would be handy if you don't want to hard-code the value in the program.

```
data _null_;
  set trt;
  vlabel_Var2 = vlabel(var2); *assign value to a variable;
  call symputx('vlabel_var2',vlabel_var2); *assign to macro variable;
  stop;  *only process one line;
run;

proc sql;
  CREATE TABLE all AS
  SELECT DISTINCT a.*,
                  b.var1, LOG(b.var2) AS log_var2 label="Log of &vlabel_var2."                 
  FROM pop AS a
  INNER JOIN trt AS b
    ON a.study=b.study AND a.subj=b.subj
  ;
QUIT;
```

You could of course keep out the "Log of" part if you want *just* the original label, it's just included to show you could also add that.

Comment: Thank you, so it looks like there is not a way of keeping the label within the proc sql step, but yes that macro variable would work, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
PROC SQL;
CREATE TABLE all AS
SELECT DISTINCT a.*,
              b.var1, LOG(b.var2) AS var2                    
FROM pop AS a
INNER JOIN trt AS b
ON a.study=b.study AND a.subj=b.subj;
QUIT;
```

by this you would do the log operation and return the value to a variable named var2. or did i misunderstand you case?

if you want the label particular you could do

```
log(b.var2) as var2 label=" you named it"
```